# Изменить цвет кнопки если внесены изменения

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Есть `Button1` который сохраняет изменения в `RichTextBox1`. Как сделать, так чтобы когда пользователь что-то напишет в `RichTextBox1` то `Button1` поменяет свой цвет на зеленый, а если пользователь сохранит файл нажав на этот `Button1`, то `Button1` примет свой стандартный цвет (например черный)? В случае если пользователь что-то опять допишет, то `Button1` станет опять зеленым.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно подписаться на событие `richTextBox1_TextChanged`:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Сохранение файла
    button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
}
```

Comment: А если я хочу указать нестандартный цвет? Например #29cca3 или 41; 204; 163

Comment: @Kaya https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(41, 204, 163);`